# Play mp3 from shell and get equalizer values

Tags: shell, equalizer

i had an idea to visualize a mp3 (the bass ups and downs), like some addons for winamp (e.g. http://www.berlinpix.com/tl_files/berlinpix/blog/frequenzanalyse-bins.jpg ).
i also want to play the mp3 file from the linux shell, get the equalizer values and process them (visualize with a script)

But i really dont know which program can do this. i read about some programs which can play a mp3 from shell, but none of them returns the values i need.
is this possible? and if it is, do you know a program who can do this? thank you

Comment: Have you tried `sox`?

Comment: no i haven't tried it yet. is there a way to get these equalizer values?